# CNN doesn't improve its performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Here the problem, I have a dataset 2200x39, I know... very poor. Where 38 are the features (texture and statistic) and the last column is the output class which could be 0 or 1. My dataset is balanced (1100 "1" and 1100 "0").

I'm trying to improve my performance which is stuck in 0.69 for loss and 0.49 for accuracy. I tried to add a layer, to add neurons, different parameters. Nothing, values of accuracy and loss change just a bit.

So, first of all, I import all the stuff I need

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization, Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then I prepar my data and split 80% training set and 20% validation test

```
# fix a seed for reproducing same results if we wish to train and evaluate our network more than once
seed = 9
np.random.seed(seed)

# load dataset
dataset = np.loadtxt('tr_set.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
# Show the first 10 rows
print(dataset[1:10])

# Delete the first column with the patient index

dataset = dataset[:,1:42]

# Split into input (features) and output variables
X = dataset[:,2:40]
Y = dataset[:,40]

# Counting elements in class 0 and in class 1
count_0 = 0
count_1 = 0

for i in Y:
    if i == 0:
        count_0 = count_0 + 1
    if i == 1:
        count_1 = count_1 + 1

print("Number of elements in 0 class:", count_0)
print("Number of elements in 1 class:", count_1)

# The dataset is balanced

# Split into training set(80%) and validation set (20%)
(X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val) = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)
```

And here my model after I reshape X_train and X_val due to using Conv1D

```
# Create the model
opt = SGD(lr=0.00001)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform', input_shape=(1,38)))
model.add(BatchNormalization()) # It is used to normalize the input layer by adjusting and scaling the activations.
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.summary()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
# model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.summary()
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()

# compile the model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), epochs=15, batch_size=10)
# w_data = model.get_weights()
```

What it is wrong, I delete the max-pooling because I have problems with dimension (Something like subtracting 2 from 1)?

Comment: Have you scaled your feature vector before feeding ? I assume the range of texture and statistic value is different, therefore, you should scale both type of feature in the same range. What's the reason of using Conv1D (useful for extracting spatial pattern) just before output layer? If you think spatial pattern/feature is contributing towards decision then using Conv1D in the earlier layer is more effective i guess. Have you tried without BatchNormalization? Hope considering these questions will help. 
Moreover fundamental ML methods (e.g. SVM) might be a good choice given scarcity of data.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply and your advises. I'll try to scale all my feature, maybe using `sklearn.preprocessing.scale`...? By the way I changed my model and now it's a full CNN, learning by features.

`opt = SGD(lr=0.0001)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(16, 3, padding="same", activation="relu" input_shape=(38,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))`

Comment: At this point I have another problem: 
 model.add(Conv1D(16, 3, padding="same", activation="relu" input_shape=(38,1)))
                                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax in input shape.
My x_train is (1760,38,1)
my x_val is (440,38,1)